# Как скрыть контент на сайте?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Всем привет! Вопрос такой:
Есть сайт с блоками(разными) на странице. На первом экране картинка во всю высоту окна, по центру Input-поле, в которое нужно ввести пароль, который человек увидит в листовке/получит от меня. 
До ввода этого пароля на странице больше ничего нету, регистрироваться на сайте тоже не нужно. 
Вводим пароль - появляется контент. Идеально, если без перезагрузки страницы, но можно и с ней. 
Делаю на CMS Wordpress

Comment: Без запроса только шифрованный JS, и то не факт, думаю вам нужно прикрутить форму Ajax для ввода пароля  и отправки пост запроса на сервер, в ответе получить контент и отобразить его клиенту. (движок здесь роли не играет ) придётся писать всё самому.

Comment: @DigitalCore Спасибо за идею! А если повесить на поле ввода кнопку, а в кнопку проверку на совпадение - и изменение css на блоках (а изначально display:none; им прописать)?
Понимаю, что не профессиональный метод, но сработает?

Comment: Решать конечно вам, но это плохая идея - приду я на ваш сайт в консоли браузера изменю стили  всё не нужно никакого пароля, что ещё хуже что в исходном коде будет хеш пароля как минимум, или вообще сам пароль. И да при Ajax запросе страницу перегружать не нужно .

Answer (score 0):

Поставь блок на весь экран с формой, которая отображается при значении false, проверь валидацию пароля и изменяй значение на true.
Но опять же, любой умник снесет этот блок через дев тулз.
Если контента мало, то лучше на него ставить условие. Много - авторизация.

Answer (score 0):

Какие вообще проблемы. Показываете форму ввода пароля, отправляете введённый пароль через ajax, проверяете его на стороне сервера. При правильном пароле - возвращаете контент в ответе ajax, и выводите его на странице.

Про ajax в WP на русском [тут](https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html).